# Difficulty getting error when running flutter doctor

Tags: download, dart, flutter

It ran smoothly in the beginning, but after a while I get this :

> Downloading windows-x64 tools...
>   Download failed.
>   URL:
>   https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra/flutter/1c26bf8c4b55f4fa5f0d175768a1a0cc115c70b2/windows-x64/artifacts.zip
>   Error: 403 Forbidden"

I have tried to change flutter directory, but it didn't help.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy, corporate firewall, ...?

Comment: yes i use proxy because im from a country where google is blocked.

Comment: any suggestions GünterZöchbauer ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy or firewall follow the instructions in these documents

https://flutter.io/community/china

https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/troubleshoot#pub-get-fails-from-behind-a-corporate-firewall

```
export https_proxy=hostname:port
```

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Workarounds-for-common-issues#hot-reload-not-working

```
export NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost
```

Comment: The question is why flutter doesn't respect system wide proxy settings and has to be set on every session? It's weirder when you find out `flutter` by its own respects system wide proxy settings and only `flutter doctor` fails to do so.

Comment: I generally added this `export NO_PROXY=127.0.0.1,localhost,::1`  that is to be working as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had Same issue and i resolve that with do following tips.

if you are Forced to use proxy for any reason, you need to set proxy true.

to do that, at first run this in terminal:

**On Linux/macOS:**

```
export https_proxy=hostname:port
```

**On Windows Command Prompt:**

```
set https_proxy=hostname:port
```

**On Windows PowerShell**

```
$Env:https_proxy="hostname:port"
```

Comment: GOOGLE REALLY!!!. Even by setting proxy system wide we have to set proxy settings on every damn session. Wowww

Comment: Yeah, Unfortunately we should set that manually in command line... and honestly, I don't know why!!!

Comment: With Linux/Mac you can make this setting permanent by adding the commands to your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc` or `.profile`.

Answer (score 0):

I am using linux ,
in terminal i ran

```
export https_proxy=10.32.0.1:8080
// It is my proxy:port
```

and then ran

```
flutter run
```